# Вывод переменных hadoop программы c помощью log4j

Tags: java, map-reduce, переменные, log4j, linux

Я написал hadoop программу с использованием log4j (привожу только шаг Map, работа которого не оправдала мои ожидания)

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class ParallelIndexation {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Map.class.getName());

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            DOMConfigurator.configure("/folder/log4j.xml");
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            Path localPath = new Path("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt");
            Path hdfsPath=new Path("hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/user/hadoop/paths.txt");
            Path localPath1 = new Path("/usr/countcomputers.txt");                
            Path hdfsPath1=new Path("hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/user/hadoop/countcomputers.txt");
            if (!fs.exists(hdfsPath))
            {
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath, hdfsPath);
            };
            if (!fs.exists(hdfsPath1))
            {
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath1, hdfsPath1);
            };          
            FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(hdfsPath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = br.readLine();
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(hdfsPath1)));
            int CountComputers;
            String result=br1.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                paths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    logger.debug("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");    
                }
            logger.debug("CountComputers=" + CountComputers + "\n");
```

Привожу файл `/folder/log4j.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%-5p][%-16.16t][%32.32c] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Но несмотря на строки программы

```
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    logger.debug("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");    
                }
            logger.debug("CountComputers=" + CountComputers + "\n");
```

в результате выполнения команды

```
./hadoop jar /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/ParallelIndexation.jar org.myorg.ParallelIndexation /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output -D mapred.map.tasks=1 1> resultofexecute.txt 2>&1
```

в файле resultofexecute.txt не оказалось вывода соответствующих переменных (содержимое которого привожу ниже):

```
args[0]=/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input
13/04/19 22:23:19 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/04/19 22:23:19 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
13/04/19 22:23:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201304192207_0001
13/04/19 22:23:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/04/19 22:23:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 100%
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201304192207_0001
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 15
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=10343
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=7555
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=21536
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=16252928
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
13/04/19 22:23:45 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
```

Помогите, вывести нужные переменные.

Comment: @ivan89: Вы на 100% уверены, что hadoop и вся простыня кода релевантны для вашей проблемы? Попробуйте найти **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему, очень уж не хочется читать все 140 строк кода.

Comment: @VladD я убрал обработку путей и оставил только код, касающийся чтения путей из `hdfs` файлов и их вывод в лог.

Comment: @ivan89: а так работает:

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException
    {
        DOMConfigurator.configure("/folder/log4j.xml");
        logger.debug("test");    
    }

?

Comment: Ну да, я вот тоже хотел сказать что логгер конфигурацию свою не подхватывает

Comment: @Mage я еще не попробовал пример VladD, но хочу вас спросить: вы хотели сказать, говоря, что логгер конфигурацию свою не подхватывает, что 

    DOMConfigurator.configure("/folder/log4j.xml");
не работает (я делал согласно http://www.skipy.ru/useful/logging.html). Каким же образом задается конфигурация логгера, если вы подразумевали именно это?

Answer (score 1):

```
<root>
    <priority value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
```

мне кажется уровень логгера не тот задан :), поменяйте ERROR на DEBUG

Comment: @Mage я изменил уровень логгера на `DEBUG` во всех файлах `/folder/log4j.xml` на всех подчиненных узлах (а значит и  на узле, на котором выполнялся `mapper`), но несмотря на это файл вывода остался тем же.

Comment: @Mage превратите ваш ответ в коментарий,  чтобы вопрос перешел в категорию неотвеченных и больше пользователей посмотрело его.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема мне кажется здесь:

`DOMConfigurator.configure("/folder/log4j.xml");`

Согласно [документации](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html) аргумент функции или имя файла находящегося в CLASSPATH или полный URL на файл. А у вас ни два ни полтора - указан полный путь, который не воспринимается. Соответственно логгер у вас не конфигурируется.

**P.S.** Более традиционно, используется не XML конфигуратор логгера, а в виде текстового файла log4.properties

Comment: @Barmaley а каким образом задается полный URL на файл (на любой - xml или текстовый)?

Comment: также хочу спросить всех ( а также тех, кто уже пытался мне помочь - @VladD, @Mage, @Barmaley ) кто имеет представление о `hadoop`: как вы считаете правильно ли Chris White на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111746/output-of-variables-of-the-hadoop-program-with-the-help-of-log4j заметил, что Log4j выводит сообщения в task логи, а не в файл, в который я перенаправил вывод консоли?

Comment: @Barmaley я на главной и подчиненных машинах сделал согласно http://hashcode.ru/questions/213931/unix-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%83c%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-classpath-%D0%B2-linux и установил `CLASPATH=/folder` (`export CLASSPATH=/folder`), но несмотря на это (`mapper`, как и `reducer` выполняются на подчиненных машинах) значения переменных не вывелись в файл.